# Android camera works on Emulator but not on Phone?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, camera

I am using Android Studio to create an Application. I wanted the system to access the camera of the phone. It worked on the Emulator, I was able to take a pic and set the picture as an Image in the ImageView.

However, I started using my phone to run and the camera doesn't work. Usually when I clicked the ImageButton, the camera opens up but now, it redirects me back to my previously opened page.

Here is my code:

```
public class DriverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnDriverBack, btnDriverSubmit;
ImageButton ibtnDriverPhoto;
ImageView imageDriver;
EditText etDriverFirstName, etDriverLastName, etDriverMiddleName, etDriverBDay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ibtnDriverPhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtnDriverPhoto);
    imageDriver = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDriver);

    etDriverFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDriverFirstName);
    etDriverMiddleName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDriverMiddleName);
    etDriverLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDriverLastName);
    etDriverBDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDriverBDay);

    ibtnDriverPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(camera, 1);
        }
    });

    btnDriverBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDriverBack);
    btnDriverBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent driveBack = new Intent(DriverActivity.this, SummaryActivity.class);
            startActivity(driveBack);
        }
    });

    btnDriverSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDriverSubmit);
    btnDriverSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent driverSubmit = new Intent(DriverActivity.this, CreditCardActivity.class);
            startActivity(driverSubmit);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1)
    {
        Bitmap license = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageDriver.setImageBitmap(license);
    }
}
```

I have set the correct Uses Permissions. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!! :)

Comment: i think your phone's android version is > Lollipop. So you must request run time permissions to use device camera.

Comment: @SudheeshR Thank you, my version is indeed higher than Lollipop! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first try this

```
private final int REQUEST_CAMERA_USAGE = 200;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_USAGE);
            } else {

            }
        }



 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA_USAGE:
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This Permission is needed for the app to work perfectly!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have above Lollipop version then add runtime permission

Answer (score 0):

To check if it is a permission issue go to settings->your_app->permissions and manually set them true , if the issue resolves then add runtime permission in your code before opening camera.